# Pass data between controllers while pageload without using $rootscope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers like below,

```
app.controller('ParentMenuController',
    function ($scope,MenuService) {
        $scope.contentLoaded = false;        
        $scope.showButton = false;
        $scope.showButton = MenuService.getStatus();
});
```

Controller2:

```
app.controller('ChildMenuController',
    function ($scope,MenuService) {
        MenuService.setStatus(true);
});
```

Service:

```
app.factory('MenuService', function ($q,$http) {    
    var status= false;
    var setStatus=function(newObj){
        status=newObj;
    };

    var getStatus=function(){
        return status;
    };

    return {
        getStatus:getStatus,
        setStatus:setStatus
    };
});
```

I am not able to set the status to true, but the below line of coding is not at all executing, so the status is always false.

```
$scope.showButton = MenuService.getStatus();
```

On button click or any action from user i can trigger the event, but my requirement is while page load, the button should not be visible. When childMenu controller executes, then parent controller button should be visible. I dont want to use $broadcast which requires $rootscope.

Note: My controller and html has hundereds of lines. I just pasted here required code for this functionality. ChildMenuController(childMenu.html) has separate html and ParentMenuController(parentMenu.html) has separete html.

So $scope.showButton is not available in ChildMenucontroller. Both html is used as directive. Main html is index.html.

Comment: Do you have a mistake in your controller name definition 'ChileMenuController'?

Comment: corrected it, but that's typo mistake while posting here.

Comment: Have you tried binding to MenuService.status instead of calling the getStatus method?

Comment: Could you share the html

Answer (score 0):

Actually your service is getting called and this piece of line is executing

`$scope.showButton = MenuService.getStatus();`

but once your `child controller` got loaded you are only setting the status but in order to show button you should getStatus after setting it
Like this,

```
app.controller('ChildMenuController', function($scope, MenuService) {
 MenuService.setStatus(true);
 $scope.$parent.showButton =  MenuService.getStatus();
});
```

this will set the button to true and it will be shown.

I have done a sample with your code please take a look into it

[DEMO](http://embed.plnkr.co/PZE1sqgCxhZbCqe3rQJT/preview)

Comment: but $scope.showButton will not be availlable in childMenuController. thats in parent html not in child html

Comment: to update your parent controller object just use `$scope.$parent.yourParentObj` in child controller.
 For your scenario it will be `$scope.$parent.showButton =  MenuService.getStatus();` Just see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

See this sample:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TepAZGOAZZzQgjUdSpVF?p=preview

You need to use a wrapper object so that it's properties are changed instead of the main object.

```
app.controller('ParentMenuController',
    function ($scope,MenuService) {
        $scope.contentLoaded = false;
        $scope.showButton = MenuService.getStatus();
});

app.controller('ChildMenuController',
    function ($scope,MenuService) {
        MenuService.setStatus(true);
});

app.factory('MenuService', function ($q,$http) {    
    var status= {value:false};
    var setStatus=function(newObj){
        status.value=newObj;
    };

    var getStatus=function(){
        return status;
    };

    return {
        getStatus:getStatus,
        setStatus:setStatus
    };
});
```

It's exactly the same as your code, but state is now an object with a value property. The state object is always the same one so that when the value is changed in the service the changes are propagated to everyone that has ever requested that object.